# Search through all values in custom object but only show a few of the values in a ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I'm using a firebase-database to contain data which I want to be able to search through. I can insert my data from Firebase into an object. I want to be able to search through all elements in all objects, but only want two values shown in the ListView. I have the following code which retrieve data from Firebase, inserts it into an object and returns two values, which I'm able to search through.

My problem is as said that I can easily make it search through all elements by simply returning all in the "getData()", but I only want the Name and Phone Number shown in the ListView.
Anyone who have an idea on how to do that?

Object class:

```
private String car_Value;
private String interest;
private String driverLicenseNr;
private String name;
private String personNr;
private String phone_Number;

public Buyers(Map<String,String> map){
    car_Value = map.get("Bil");
    interest = map.get("Interesse");
    driverLicenseNr = map.get("Kørekortnr");
    name = map.get("Navn");
    personNr = map.get("Personnr");
    phone_Number = map.get("Telefonnr");
}
String getData()
{
    return (name + " " + phone_Number);
}
```

Searching class:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ListView mUserList;
private SearchView searchModule;
private ArrayList<String> mUsernames = new ArrayList<>();
//private ArrayList<String> filteredUsernames = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_existing_customer);

    searchModule = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.SearchTab);
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buyers");
    mUserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UserListView);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mUsernames);
    //final ArrayAdapter<String> filteredArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filteredUsernames);
    mUserList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) childSnapshot.getValue();
                Buyers buyerList = new Buyers(map);
                mUsernames.add(buyerList.getData());
                //filteredUsernames.add(buyerList.getData());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            searchModule.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to customize ArrayAdapter to use a special Filter object.

It would be easier to store all data outside of the ListView, and only add the filtered data to the ListView. *(then there is no need to customize ArrayAdapter)*

Comment: I agree. My problem is that I'm new, and I can't see a way to add all the data to an arraylist and then filter those data and transfer it to another arraylist, which can then be shown.

Comment: Well, you can have an `ArrayList<Buyers> all_buyers` somewhere, independently of the ListView, that contains all buyers. You could write an `ArrayList<String> filter_buyers (ArrayList<Buyers> all_buyers, String query)` function, that iterates through the list, checks all fields in all objects, adds all matching objects to a new list (the one it returns), but adds only the `buyer.getData()`'s result to it (a simple String). It returns this array of simple strings. (I almost wrote it now :) ). onQueryTextSubmit () would call this function, and update the ListView with the result...